# Drop Azure SQL table from Databricks notebook

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to drop a table in my Azure SQL server database (SQL version 2019) via my Databricks notebook.

In my notebook, I have established by jdbc connection to the azure sql server. I have a test query to confirm the connection. This works fine.

However, my code to drop a table on the SQL database does not fail but it does not drop the table. The table still exists.

```
table_name = "dbo.json_staging"
spark.sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}")
```

Output: Out[35]: DataFrame[]

Comment: Is the target table configured as an external table?

Comment: @shoaib Maroof The DROP in Spark SQL is a DDL command, that drops the table with all its table data (only for the internal Hive table)

Comment: Do you know then how to drop an Azure SQL Server table that I am connecting to via JDBC?

Comment: Yes In %scala I can help you with.

Comment: let  me provide you solution.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula would prefer python if possible

Comment: pyodbc worked by installing odbc driver package



%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the below code to DROP the table from the Azure SQL database Using Azure Databricks.

I have tried it using the **SCALA**

```
%scala
import  java.util.Properties
import  java.sql.DriverManager
val  jdbcUsername = "admin02"
val  jdbcPassword = "Welcome@1"
val  driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
val  jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserveraug09.database.windows.net:1433;database=db002;user=admin02@sqlserveraug09;password=Welcome@1;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
val  connectionProperties = new  Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)
val  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
val  stmt = connection.createStatement()
val  sql = "DROP Table employee_new"
stmt.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```

**Output:**
[image]

I have **DROPED** the Table named **employee_new**

[image]

Comment: I have tried using the Pyodbc and here is the code import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver};'
                       'SERVER=sqlserveraug09.database.windows.net:1433;'
                       'DATABASE=db002;UID=admin02;'
                       'PWD=Welcome@1')
conn.execute('DROP Table sales')


Giving me error Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: I tried also with Pyodbc. It did not work.
With my jdbc connection, I am trying to call it via code below:

df.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table="query", mode="overwrite", properties=jdbc_connection_properties)

code does not fail on error but it does not drop the table.

Comment: try using the SCALA for dropping the table and see

Comment: SQLServerException: Cannot drop the table 'dbo.staging_json', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

when I used the scala code.

Comment: just use the table name and see also check if you have required permissions to drop table?

Comment: it worked with your scala code :)

I tried replicating with python but it's not working.

Comment: any chance you can test with Python